# Including interaction terms without main effects in rms::cph

Tags: interaction, cox-regression

I need to retain an interaction term but excluding main effects in a Cox model with rms::cph.
With survival::coxph i usually do

> coxph(Surv(time, death)~a:b) instead of coxph(Surv(time, death)~a*b)

but this is not working with Harrel's rms::cph.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

`rms` does not support this and I would not recommend it in general.  If you need a special model fitted where you have paid enormous attention to the zero origin of each variable you can create product terms before passing to `cph`.

Comment: Thanks Prof Harrel. I'm working to derive a predictive score. The full model is cph(Surv(t, d)~a+b+c+d+e+f*(g+rcs(h, 3)). The reduced model obtained with fastbw should include a, c, f, f * g, f * rcs(h, 3). This is the rationale behind my question... However, if i well understood, you suggest to turn around the problem by creating z=f * g, right? But i don't think this is feasible for f * rcs(h, 3)...

Comment: You can create any product terms you want but did `fastbw` really remove a main effect without removing the interaction term containing it?  That is highly un-recommended.